# How to use @Observable Macro in Unit Tests in Swift?

Tags: swift, unit-testing, macros, observable

How can I make `assertMacroExpansion(_:expandedSource:macros)` expand the `@Observable` macro? I tried passing in `Observable.self` in the `macros` parameter but that didn't work. I also tried importing `ObservationMacros` but was unsuccessful. Does anyone know how to do this? It's not expanding the macro and is leaving the code unchanged.